# Get Order Details by Order Id

Tags: magento, search, magento-1.9

I need to retrieve an order from Magento by its `id`.
How do I load a specific order by `id`?

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow. I clearly see you intended to give us the more information you could in your question but, when we say "please write down what you tried so far" we mean "post the code or your code attempt so far". You actual "I tried" was not really relevant to your question, to be honest.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In magento every order has two IDs

1. Order ID - is Magento internal order ID
2. Order Increment ID - is the ID display on communicate (email, etc) with your customer

See [Confusion with order id, order increment id and I am not getting order id as 20001201](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/26250/confusion-with-order-id-order-increment-id-and-i-am-not-getting-order-id-as-200)

To load order by Id

```
 Mage::getModel("sales/order")->load(1);
```

To load order byIncrement id

```
 Mage::getModel('sales/order')->loadByIncrementId('10000001')
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use following code.

```
$order = Mage::getModel('sales/order')->load(23789); // order id here
print_r($order->getData());
```

Answer (score 2):

If you know the real order ID then,

```
$orderDetails = Mage::getModel("sales/order")->load($orderId);
```

Answer (score 1):

To get the order data by order increment Id

```
Mage::getModel('sales/order')->loadByIncrementId('10000001')->getData();
```

To get the order data by order entity Id

```
Mage::getModel('sales/order')->load('245')->getData();
```